# LaTeX tables: How to make sure text in a cell doesn't get out it?

Tags: latex

The text from some of my sells spills over the next ones. How can I make sure the text is wrap inside the same cell?
Additionally, how can I make the first column wider than the others?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,final]{vlsithesis}
\doctype{Thesis}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage[algo2e, ruled, vlined]{algorithm2e} 
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=25.4 mm,
 right= 25.4mm,
 top=20mm,
 }

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tblr}{  colspec{|X[valign=h]|X[valign=m]|X[valign=m]|X[valign=m]|X[valign=m]|X[valign=m]|X[valign=m]|X[valign=m]|},
row{1}={font=\bfseries},
cell{1}{1}={halign=c}
}
\hline
 Variables & N & Mean & SD & Min & Max & Range & SE \\ 
\hline
  ICT index & 51.00 & 16.46 & 3.89 & 8.89 & 25.59 & 16.70 & 0.54 \\ 
\hline
  Educational Resilience  & 51.00 & 455.73 & 186.32 & 97.00 & 879.00 & 782.00 & 26.09 \\ 
\hline 
  Log GDP per capita & 50.00 & 9.83 & 0.90 & 8.35 & 11.66 & 3.31 & 0.13 \\ 
\hline
  Literacy Rate & 50.00 & 97.95 & 1.91 & 93.23 & 99.96 & 6.73 & 0.27 \\ 
  \hline
  Strengh of health system index & 50.00 & 6.08 & 1.60 & 3.00 & 9.00 & 6.00 & 0.23 \\ 
  \hline
  COVID-19 cases & 50.00 & 276155.28 & 783990.64 & 1366.38 & 5012137.53 & 5010771.15 & 110873.02 \\ 
  \hline
  COVID-19 deaths  & 50.00 & 9240.03 & 23148.98 & 10.65 & 135930.19 & 135919.54 & 3273.76 \\ 
  \hline
  Stringency index & 50.00 & 55.45 & 9.47 & 34.47 & 75.66 & 41.19 & 1.34 \\ 
  \hline
  Government Response & 50.00 & 52.29 & 6.24 & 37.13 & 65.87 & 28.74 & 0.88 \\
  \hline
  Containtment of the virus  & 50.00 & 52.13 & 7.50 & 35.23 & 69.06 & 33.83 & 1.06 \\ 
  \hline
  Economic Support  & 50.00 & 53.40 & 16.18 & 18.26 & 83.26 & 65.00 & 2.29 \\
  \hline
  Health Policy Index (2020)  & 48.00 & 8.65 & 1.23 & 6.13 & 11.32 & 5.19 & 0.18 \\ 
  \hline
  Critical Fatality Ratio (squared)  & 50.00 & 15.69 & 7.08 & 5.56 & 45.25 & 39.69 & 1.00 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tblr}
\caption{Summary Statistics}
\label{table:2}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Here is how it currently look:

[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting . Having to remove all the empty lines before even starting to work on a solution is a bit annoying.

Comment: Please also make a compilable [mre] instead of a code fragment. Without knowing your documentclass it is hard to make a useful guess how you increase the text width so that your table has more space.

Comment: Thank you for removing all these empty lines, but please don't forget to add a compilable [mre] including a documentclass and the packages necessary to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long numbers can't be broken across lines and your page only has so much available space. A couple of strategies to nevertheless fit your table on the page:

- pay attention to significant figures. Given the values of the standard deviations, it makes little sense to give all your numbers with two decimal places
- decrease the padding around the vertical line (or better, have a look at the booktabs user guide which shows how professional looking tables can look like (there is a library for tabularray, so the same layout can also be done with this package))
- change the ration of the column width, e.g. with `X[1.3,valign=h,halign=l]` for the first column
- use a smaller font
- make the margins smaller
- use a bigger paper
- I was already wondering this yesterday, but isn't it strange to have the 1-1 cell centred if the rest of the table is all left aligned?

---

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,final]{article}
%\doctype{Thesis}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage[algo2e, ruled, vlined]{algorithm2e} 
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
% left=25.4 mm,
% right= 25.4mm,
 top=20mm,
 }

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\small
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={|X[1.3,valign=h,halign=l]|X[valign=m]|X[valign=m]|X[valign=m]|X[valign=m]|X[valign=m]|X[valign=m]|X[valign=m]|},
  row{1}={font=\bfseries},
  cell{1}{1}={halign=c},
  colsep=2pt
}
\hline
 Variables & N & Mean & SD & Min & Max & Range & SE \\ 
\hline
  ICT index & 51.00 & 16.46 & 3.89 & 8.89 & 25.59 & 16.70 & 0.54 \\ 
\hline
  Educational Resilience  & 51.00 & 455.73 & 186.32 & 97.00 & 879.00 & 782.00 & 26.09 \\ 
\hline 
  Log GDP per capita & 50.00 & 9.83 & 0.90 & 8.35 & 11.66 & 3.31 & 0.13 \\ 
\hline
  Literacy Rate & 50.00 & 97.95 & 1.91 & 93.23 & 99.96 & 6.73 & 0.27 \\ 
  \hline
  Strengh of health system index & 50.00 & 6.08 & 1.60 & 3.00 & 9.00 & 6.00 & 0.23 \\ 
  \hline
  COVID-19 cases & 50.00 & 276155.28 & 783990.64 & 1366.38 & 5012137.53 & 5010771.15 & 110873.02 \\ 
  \hline
  COVID-19 deaths  & 50.00 & 9240.03 & 23148.98 & 10.65 & 135930.19 & 135919.54 & 3273.76 \\ 
  \hline
  Stringency index & 50.00 & 55.45 & 9.47 & 34.47 & 75.66 & 41.19 & 1.34 \\ 
  \hline
  Government Response & 50.00 & 52.29 & 6.24 & 37.13 & 65.87 & 28.74 & 0.88 \\
  \hline
  Containtment of the virus  & 50.00 & 52.13 & 7.50 & 35.23 & 69.06 & 33.83 & 1.06 \\ 
  \hline
  Economic Support  & 50.00 & 53.40 & 16.18 & 18.26 & 83.26 & 65.00 & 2.29 \\
  \hline
  Health Policy Index (2020)  & 48.00 & 8.65 & 1.23 & 6.13 & 11.32 & 5.19 & 0.18 \\ 
  \hline
  Critical Fatality Ratio (squared)  & 50.00 & 15.69 & 7.08 & 5.56 & 45.25 & 39.69 & 1.00 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tblr}
\caption{Summary Statistics}
\label{table:2}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]